# Why are enums not always working when call by a rest api?

Tags: java, enums

I have a dto using an enum (let's call it Comparison) :

```
public enum Comparison {
    comparisonA, comparisonB, comparisonC, comparisonD
}
```

and

```
public class ComparisonDto {
    public Comparison operator;
    public Integer value;

    // with getter and setter
}
```

It works great when compiled with my computer but others developers have a problem : the Comparison value that is used isn't recognized anymore.
The json is under the following form when calling the path :

```
{
  "value" : 10,
  "operator" : "comparisonA"
}
```

The most common error with this case is an "unrecognized data type".
For instance, the api is under this form :

```
@Path("/path-to-call")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public interface ApiRs {

    @POST
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    ResponseStatus create(ComparisonDto comparisonDto);
}
```

Spring is not used.

Comment: Are the other devs using *jackson for the serialization/deserialization* as well?

Comment: How do other devs deserialize it? Provide code please. It's impossible to help them help, when it's not clear what they do

Comment: The code is the same for everyone. And actually, jackson doesn't look like it's used for this one so i'm gonna remove the mention...

Comment: Could you please post the whole error?

Comment: Will do when we got one !

Comment: IIRC the default in Spring for method parameter mapping is query parameters. Unless this has changed, you likely want `@RequestBody` on your method parameter.

Comment: We don't use spring.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having a simple Typo that messes everything. I think it's not the comparison field but rather the value field that is incorrect.

If the json being sent is really:

```
{
  "values" : 10,
  "operator" : "comparisonA"
}
```

Then it should be

```
{
  "value" : 10,
  "operator" : "comparisonA"
}
```

Remove the extra s from "values" and hopefully the data type should be recognized and everything will work fine again.

Comment: My bad, that's a typo in the post.